# Getting friends' large pictures

Tags: javascript, authentication, facebook-graph-api

This is my script

```
    var accessToken = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    var path = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?";
    var queryParams = [accessToken, 'callback=facebookGet' ,'fields=picture,name', 'type=large'];
    var query = queryParams.join('&');
    var url = path + query;

    // use jsonp to call the graph
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Now, I get the friends' pictures, but they're in the lowest resolution. I want large pictures, how do I do it?

edit: I found a workaround. Instead of using

```
friend.picture
```

I used

```
friend.picture.replace("_q","_n")
```

Comment: Where is the code for "facebookGet"?

Comment: var friends=new Array();

function facebookGet(user) {
 friends=user.data;
}

Answer (score 1):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

`SELECT uid, name, pic_big FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me())`